MSAL V1.x how to update client id and authority dynamically (i am using angular 7)
I am using the @azure/msal-angular version ^1.1.2, and I am facing an issue on how to update the MsalModule dynamically
i am refering the code base https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/msal-angular-v1/samples/msal-angular-samples/angular7-sample-app/src/app/app.module.ts
I have another API which is returning this configuration after the API call how to update those details? MsalModule.forRoot({})
@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
   imports: [  MsalModule.forRoot({ auth: {
            clientId: '',
            authority: '',
            redirectUri: '',
            postLogoutRedirectUri: '',
            navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true
        } },
            {
                popUp: !isIE,
                consentScopes: [
                    'profile',
                    'user.read',
                    'offline_access'
                ],
                unprotectedResources: ['https://www.microsoft.com'],
                protectedResourceMap,
                extraQueryParameters: {},
            })
            ]

Because MSAL 1.x does not support the .instance method (which is available in version 2.x), I am able to update the configuration dynamically in version 2.x(using msalService.instance), but not in 1.x. Could you please guide me on how to update the configuration dynamically in version 1.x?

After a lot of trial and error, I finally found the solution to update the MSAL 1.x configuration dynamically. Here is the code:
import {MsalService } from '@azure/msal-angular';
import * as Msal from 'msal';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  private msalApp: Msal.UserAgentApplication;
  private defaultConfig: Msal.Configuration = {
    auth: {
      clientId: 'initial-client-id',  // Default clientId
      authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/your-tenant-id',  // Default authority
    },
    cache: {
      cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
      storeAuthStateInCookie: false,
    },
  };

  constructor(private authService: MsalService) { }
      ngOnInit() {
      }


  loginAzure() {
    this.msalApp = null;
    const updatedConfig: Msal.Configuration = {
      auth: { // update dynamic data here
        clientId: config.clientId, // dynamic clientId
        authority: config.authority, // dynamic authority
        redirectUri: config.redirectUrl, // dynamic redirectUrl
        postLogoutRedirectUri: config.redirectUrl, // dynamic redirectUrl
        navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true
      },
      cache: this.defaultConfig.cache,
    };
    this.msalApp = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(updatedConfig);
    this.msalApp.loginPopup().then(response => {
      console.log('response', response)
    }).catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }

}

